# Ram space exhausted while creating a Binary Search Tree of 60000 elements

Tags: c++, ram

I am trying to build a huge binary search tree:

```
class Node
{
public:
   int value;
   shared_ptr<Node> left;
   Node* right;

   Node(int v):value(v){}
   void addLeft(){
      static int i;
      shared_ptr<Node> node=make_shared<Node>(i);
      left=node;
      cout<<i++<<endl;
      if(i<60000)
         node->addLeft();
   }
};



int main(){

   shared_ptr<Node>root=make_shared<Node>(9);
   root->addLeft();
   return 0;
}
```

I get a seg fault over running this code, in valgrind I have this report:

```
==17373== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801000
```

Any clue on how to build the BST without overflowing the RAM space?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: The people who put -1 please at least be constructive and leave a comment to explain the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Exceeding the stack is not the same as exceeding your RAM. Function calls accumulate on the stack, the problem is you are trying to place 60000 function calls and variables on the stack. Convert your function to a loop and you will be fine. It will even get rid of that terrible `static int i`.

Here is a version of your function using a `for` loop with no recursion.

```
void addLeft() 
{
    left = std::make_shared<Node>(0);

    // tail is the last element to have been added to the tree
    std::shared_ptr<Node> tail = left;
    std::cout << 0 << std::endl;

    // Add nodes from 1 to 60000 inclusively
    for (int i = 1; i <= 60000; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        tail->left = std::make_shared<Node>(i);
        tail = tail->left;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get the stack overflow with this snippet.
Have you actually tried it ?

Comment: @MarwanB Yes, I've tried it. Are you sure the example you provided is representative of what you are doing? For example, if `Node`'s constructor calls `addLeft()` this will overflow the stack. If you are still getting a stack overflow with this example, the problem lies elsewhere.